# How to use oracle advanced queue(OAQ) with node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, oracle

How to use oracle advanced queue(OAQ) with node js?

How to pull messages from oracle advanced queue(AQ) using node.js.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use oracle advanced queue in node js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54321680/how-to-use-oracle-advanced-queue-in-node-js)

Answer (score 1):

See this new section of the doc which covers using AQ: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#-23-advanced-queuing-aq There are plans to add native support for certain queuing operations, but a little PL/SQL can get things working for now.